# Usage of "Of" and "for"

Tags: prepositions

Is there a general rule governing the usage of "Of" and "For" when used in the following way:
Which is correct "My love of animals" or "My love for animals" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, there is a distinction, but both uses have their own "correctness" in different situations.

"Love of animals" seems to indicate admiration and affection in a general sense, while "love for animals" is a more personally invested, as a doting, caring, sacrificial love, perhaps stronger and more personal than the "love of animals."

"For" is more outward-focused, benefitting the object, and "of" simply draws the connection between the noun and object. Refer to this ["of" vs "for" article](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-of-and-for/) for a good distinction between the two prepositions.

Answer (score -2):

My **love for animals** is **correct** here, my **love of animals** is **senseless**

Comment: Read this link(http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10681/how-to-use-of-preposition-possession)

Comment: You're half right. The two constructions are [about equally used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+love+for+animals%2C+my+love+of+animals&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20love%20for%20animals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20love%20of%20animals%3B%2Cc0). (So *no*, "my love of animals" is *not* senseless.)

Comment: http://www.talkenglish.com/Grammar/prepositions-of-to-for.aspx

Comment: This wud help I think its well described in brief